# Preg Replace text to links with domains filter

Tags: php, regex

Hello everyone i have a problem
I have a text

```
$text = " some and text http://www.somelink2.com/html5.jpg and some text http://www.somelink.net/test/testjava/html5.html#fbid=QTb-X6fv5p1 some http://www.somelink4.org test and http://www.somelink3.org/link.html text and some text ";
```

i need to transform all text links http/s exept domains somelink3.org,somelink2.com they must be plain text

Something like this but with domains filter and not extention images:

```
function livelinked ($text){
        preg_match_all("#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)|^(jpg)^#ie", $text, $ccs);
        foreach ($ccs[3] as $cc) {
           if (strpos($cc,"jpg")==false  && strpos($cc,"gif")==false && strpos($cc,"png")==false ) {
              $old[] = "http://".$cc;
              $new[] = '<a href="http://'.$cc.'" target="_blank">'.$cc.'</a>';
           }
        }
        return str_replace($old,$new,$text);
}
```

edit: this helped me :

```
$text =  preg_replace("~((?:http|https|ftp)://(?!site.com|site2.com|site3.com)(?:\S*?\.\S*?))(?=\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)~i",'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',$text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`(?!...)` negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for such cases. Simply add `(?!somelink3.org|somelink2.com)` immediately after the protocol placeholder `://`.

```
 #((http|https|ftp)://(?!domain1|domain2)(\S*?\.\S*?))....
```

Also you shouldn't use `preg_match_all` in combination with a clumsy `str_replace` as secondary step. Instead utilize [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and put all the logic in one function.

Comment: thanks a lot , iv gor a succes ,i have some questions: why its not good to use preg match ? and when i post 2 links a got `www.domain.com/test-ajax-upload.html" target="_blank">www.domain.com/test-ajax-upload.html www.domain.com/test-ajax-upload.html" target="_blank">www.domain.com/test-ajax-upload.html`

Comment: (1) Because it's clumsy. (2) Because you also match the `\s` space character.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably condense it down and use the preg replace all

Raw Regex

```
(?:http|https|ftp)://
(\S*?\.(?:(?!(?<=\.)(?:jpg|png|gif)|\s).)*?)
(?= [\s;)\]\[{},"':<] | $ | \.\s )
```

Raw Replacement

```
<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>
```

Modifiers //xsg

*Edit:* - So I didn't catch you need to filter domain's. The regex above filters jpg/png/gif files and that is fairly complex as it is. But adding filters might be better handled with a url parser or another regex within a callback.